# Unauthorized Error in Powershell But Not In VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powershell, http, soap

I have VBA code which works fine:

```
Dim sURL As String
Dim sEnv As String
Dim xmlhtp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
Dim xmlDoc As New DOMDocument
Public Const tamhost As String = "cadd.ad2.gt.au:9045"

sURL = "http://" & tamhost & "/mweb/services/AEXTSYS4_QueryAssets"

sEnv = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=""http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"" xmlns:max=""http://www.asdf.com/asdf"">"
sEnv = sEnv & "  <soap:Body>"
sEnv = sEnv & "     <max:QueryASSET>"
sEnv = sEnv & "         <max:ASSETQuery>"
sEnv = sEnv & "             <max:ASSET>"
sEnv = sEnv & "                 <max:ASSETTAG operator=""="">asdf45412</max:ASSETTAG>"
sEnv = sEnv & "             </max:ASSET>"
sEnv = sEnv & "         </max:ASSETQuery>"
sEnv = sEnv & "     </max:QueryASSET>"
sEnv = sEnv & "  </soap:Body>"
sEnv = sEnv & "</soap:Envelope>"


' invoke the service
With xmlhtp
.Open "post", sURL, False
.setRequestHeader "Host", tamhost
.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action=""urn:processDocument"""
.send sEnv
xmlDoc.LoadXML .responseText
End With
```

I can see a valid XML string in `.responseText`

However when I convert this code to Powershell:

```
$sEnv = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>"

$sEnv += "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=""http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"" xmlns:max=""http://www.asdf.com/asdf"">"
$sEnv += "  <soap:Body>"
$sEnv += "     <max:QueryASSET>"
$sEnv += "         <max:ASSETQuery>"
$sEnv += "             <max:ASSET>"
$sEnv += "                 <max:ASSETTAG operator=""="">asdf45412</max:ASSETTAG>"
$sEnv += "             </max:ASSET>"
$sEnv += "         </max:ASSETQuery>"
$sEnv += "     </max:QueryASSET>"
$sEnv += "  </soap:Body>"
$sEnv += "</soap:Envelope>"

$soapEnvelopeXml = New-Object 'System.Xml.XmlDocument'
$soapEnvelopeXml.LoadXml($sEnv)

$tamhost = 'cadd.ad2.gt.au:9045'
$sURL = "http://$tamhost/mweb/services/AEXTSYS4_QueryAssets"

$request = [System.Net.HttpWebRequest]([System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($sURL))
$request.Host = $tamhost
$request.ContentType = 'application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action=""urn:processDocument""'
$request.Method = 'POST'

$stream = $request.GetRequestStream()
$soapEnvelopeXml.Save($stream)
$stream.Close()

$response = $request.GetResponse() #"The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."
```

I get a 401 Unauthorized error.

Why is it not working in Powershell and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed the problem:

```
$request = [System.Activator]::CreateInstance([System.Type]::GetTypeFromProgID('MSXML2.XMLHTTP'))

$request.Open('POST', $sURL, $false)
$request.SetRequestHeader('Host', $tamhost)
$request.SetRequestHeader('Content-Type', "application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action=""urn:processDocument""")
$request.Send($sEnv)
```